# How to erase rectangles drawn in uitableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, drawrect

I subclassed uitableviewcell based on this blog http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=153.
With this i can draw columns and place text in a grid.

When i reload the table, the text and grid remains there. I removed the labels using 
[[cell viewWithTag:k] removeFromSuperview]; How do i removethe grid lines that are drawn using drawrect:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `drawRect:` method is no longer drawing the grid lines, you should probably try calling `setNeedsDisplay` or `layoutSubviews` on your table view so that it forces all of the cells to redraw. Reloading the table using `reloadData` only reloads the datasource, and I don't believe it redraws unless there are changes to the model.